# Microsoft Graph API send no response required meeting invites

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create meeting invites without allowing users to Accept/Decline them. I have seen many meeting invites that have "No response required".

```
{                                                                 
    "subject":      "Microsoft Teams Meeting",                              
    "location":     {                                                       
            "displayName":  "Online Meeting"                                
    },                                                                      
    "body": {                                                               
            "contentType":  "HTML",                                         
            "content":      "Sounds good?"                                  
    },                                                                      
    "start":        {                                                       
            "dateTime":     "2022-01-18T15:04:00",                          
            "timeZone":     "Pacific Standard Time"                         
    },                                                                      
    "end":  {                                                               
            "dateTime":     "2022-01-18T16:04:00",                          
            "timeZone":     "Pacific Standard Time"                         
    },                                                                      
    "attendees": [{                                                      
                    "type": "required",                                     
                    "emailAddress": {                                       
                        "address": "umerwaqar@gmail.com"            
                    }                                                       
                }],                                                                      
    "isOnlineMeeting": false,                                           
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
}
```

I tried putting "responseRequested": false" but still seeing Accept/Decline/Tentative options.

[image: Meeting response]

But I want it to remove these options and show "No response required" like the below image

[image: no response required image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set another email address as the attendee which is different from the one we used to create the event, then it will show the "not request a response"

```
{
  "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
  "responseRequested":false,
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "Does noon work for you?"
  },
  "start": {
      "dateTime": "2022-01-21T12:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
      "dateTime": "2022-01-21T14:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
  },
  "location":{
      "displayName":"Harry's Bar"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address":"xxx@outlook.com",
        "name": "tiny wang"
      },
      "type": "required"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

`"responseRequested": false` should work for the [create event api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), because the [event object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) has the property of `responseRequested`.

But please note the [online meeting object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0) doesn't contain this property, so you can't create an online meeting without response by adding this property using [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Tiny Wang. How did you create this? Can you share the code? And you mean I need to create onlineMeeting? I am creating an Event now which sends an invite.

Comment: You can see my screenshot about my request to create the event. I mean you need to create event, but not online meeting.@UmerWaqar

Comment: I am calling this URL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_email>/events and passing "responseRequested": false but not working this way. I also tried both "isOnlineMeeting":  false and "responseRequested": false but this did not work either.

Comment: @UmerWaqar If you can try my request content? Don't forget to replace the email address

Comment: Already tried it but did not work for me. I still see Accept, Decline, and Tentative buttons.
I don't see "The organizer has not requested a response for this meeting" message

Comment: If you set another email address which is different from the one you used to create the event? For me, I create the event by my microsoft account, and the attendee email address is my outlook email.

Comment: I have used another email address to create an event. Now I see the message "The organizer has not requested a response for this meeting" but still see  Accept, Decline, and Tentative buttons. Is there a way to auto-accept it? I mean it will be auto accepted when an invite is sent.

Comment: @UmerWaqar I'm afraid it impossible. You see, the attendees are invited, if graph api can set to help the attendees to "auto accept", they need to send multi-request for each attendee, so I think it's impossible.....