# Create Outlook Event with Meet link

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to create an event on Outlook Calendar with a Meet link.
I'm sending this payload:

```
{
  "subject": "Subject",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "text",
    "content": "Content."
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-09-04T20:38:01.000Z",
    "timeZone": "Europe/London"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-09-04T20:39:00.000Z",
    "timeZone": "Europe/London"
  },
  "isOnlineMeeting": true,
  "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
}
```

In the Azure Portal my app has the following permissions: `User.Read, TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All, TeamSettings.Read.All`

It succesfully creates the meeting, but it returns `"onlineMeetingProvider": "unknown"`, and it doesn't create the meet call associated to the meeting.

Answer (score 0):

There're 2 APIs can be used to create an online meeting, that's [creating event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) and [create onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

[image]

Then according to your request body, we can see you are using the `create event` API, and this API required API permission `Calendars.ReadWrite` which you don't have it..

[image]

I'm confused why you can create the meeting but I think this might be the cause for your issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the `createEvent` api since I want to create the event and the online meeting at once. I tried to add the permission at the application level but nothing changed

Comment: I had [a test before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70766787/14574199) and it might help. Since I don't have a test resource now so I can't test again.

Comment: You mentioned `add the permission at the application level `, so pls attention that the token you should generate like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZVzz.png

Comment: I'm using `@azure/msal-node` and `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client` npm packages to create the request and handle the authentication. I meant that I added the authorization in the azure dashboard

Comment: Maybe you can find a proper sample here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code